# Storing a $_GET to $_SESSION when form is on every page Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form on every page that is a quick navigation. Based on the value of the drop-downs it will redirect to a specific page. The URL after using it will look like /page?first=abc&second=def&third=ghi. If you leave the page and go to pageB the url will just say /pageB. I'm trying to create a SESSION for second if it's set and when it's no longer set (navigating to a different page not using the quicknav) still store the value when it was set. Here is what I have so far...

```
function storeVariable {

 global $saved_second
  $store_second = $_GET['second'];
  $saved_second ='';
  if (isset($store_second)) {
    $_SESSION['second'] = $_GET['second'];
    $sessionsecond = $_SESSION['second'];
    $saved_second = $sessionsecond; 
  } 
 return $save_second

 }
```

In the header I have

```
 global $saved_second;
  echo $saved_second;
```

The above code is fine for the initial page the quick navigation goes to. It shows the value of $saved_second in the header. I'm not sure how I would say

```
 if (isset($saved_second) && (!isset($stored_second) {
 USE SESSION THAT WAS CREATED WHEN $stored_second WAS SET
```

I thought something like...

```
 if ($store_second != $sessionsecond){
```

but that doesn't work either because  the session was created in an IF statement.

Then I tried...

```
 IF (!isset($saved_second)) {
 IF (isset($_GET['second'])) {
 $_SESSION['second'] = $_GET['second'];
 $saved_second = $_SESSION['second'];
 }}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a form extension?

Comment: I'm not following the question. How else would I store the SESSION on the website where the same form is present throughout the site and resets when it's not used as the way to navigate?

Comment: Oooh. So you want the user to not lose the entered data when switching pages?

Comment: The form should clear when you use the navigation and not the quick navigation (the form). But the value of SECOND if it was filled out should be stored without being reflected in the form.